# Hydra: Overriding hydra.run.dir/working directory management with Compose API

Tags: fb-hydra

I'm attempting to use Hydra's [compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/experimental/compose_api) to launch runs programmatically instead of via CLI. This works for the most part. However, overriding `hydra.run.dir` to change the base directory doesn't seem to have the effect when using the compose API. I.e.:

```
    with hydra.experimental.initialize_config_module(config_module=config_module):
        cfg = hydra.experimental.compose(
            config_name=config_name,
            overrides=["hydra.run.dir=/tmp/workdir", ...],
            return_hydra_config=True
        )

        hydra.core.hydra_config.HydraConfig.instance().set_config(cfg)

        with omegaconf.open_dict(cfg):
            del cfg["hydra"]
```

generates a `DictConfig` with the appropriate entry for `hydra.run.dir`, but the working directory is not changed.

The compose API documentation states that not using `@hydra.main` entails forfeiting Hydra's working directory management. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compose API is stateless and is intentionally not changing the working directory, configuring the logging or changing global state and not integrating with the command line. If you need these functionalities you should consider using `@hydra.main()`.

As a workaround, you can call chdir programmatically on your end (with [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)). You will probably also need to mkdir first.